# How to catch an error on an eventEmitter that runs an async function on 'emit'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, eventemitter

I am having some trouble catching errors on `async functions` that are are run by an `eventEmitter` on `emit`.

Here is the code:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
eventEmitter.addListener('callSyncFunction', syncFunction)
eventEmitter.addListener('callAsyncFunction', asyncFunction)

function syncFunction() {
    throw new Error('Sync function error')
}

async function asyncFunction() {
    throw new Error('Async function error')
}

try {
    eventEmitter.emit('callSyncFunction')
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
// Works and prints 'Sync function error'

try {
    eventEmitter.emit('callAsyncFunction')
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
// Does not  work and gives an Unhandled promise rejection
```

I am able to catch errors when a synchronous function is called by the `eventEmitter` but unable. to catch errors when async functions are run. As suggested on https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_capture_rejections_of_promises I tried enabled `captureRejections: true` but it still does not help capture those errors.

Apart from using a library like [emittery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emittery), is there any solution to this?

Comment: As stated in the documentation, "*The handler routes the exception asynchronously to the […] `'error'` event handler*". It does not make `emit()` throw an error. Notice that event emitters are one-way streets, you can send events but you won't get anything back.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use nodejs EventEmitter to catch errors from async listeners. The `emit` method is fully synchronous.
Setting `capture Rejections: true` just allows you to catch async errors through `error` event. You should use some third-party lib for this, e.g [EventEmitter2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter2)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a wrapper Listener and resolve the `Async` function inside it

```
function WrapperListener(){
    asyncFunction().then(result=>{
            //dosomething
        }).catch(e=>{
           console.log(e)
    })
}
```

Comment: If I have a caller than wants to await the results, how can I turn the exception into another return code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this wrapper for my purposes: [events-async](https://github.com/wesleytodd/events-async).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Use '**error**' event :

**GIVEN**:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter({ captureRejections: true });
eventEmitter.on('callSyncFunction', ()=>{
    throw new Error('Sync function error')
})
eventEmitter.on('callAsyncFunction', async ()=>{
    throw new Error('Async function error')
})
```

**GIVEN**: Error handling

```
eventEmitter.on('error', (e)=>{
    console.log("Error caught: ", e.message)
})
```

**WHEN**

```
eventEmitter.emit('callSyncFunction', {})
eventEmitter.emit('callAsyncFunction',{})
```

**THEN**

Expect console output:

```
Error caught: Sync function error
Error caught: Async function error
```